# How to improve the efficiency of below query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a ten million level database. The client needs to read data and perform calculation.
Due to the large amount of data, if it is saved in the application cache, memory will be overflow and crash will occur.
If I use select statement to query data from the database in real time, the time may be too long and the number of operations on the database may be too frequent.
Is there a better way to read the database data? I use C++ and C# to access SQL Server database.

My database statement is similar to the following:

```
SELECT TOP 10 y.SourceName, MAX(y.EndTimeStamp - y.StartTimeStamp) AS ProcessTimeStamp
FROM
(
    SELECT x.SourceName, x.StartTimeStamp, IIF(x.EndTimeStamp IS NOT NULL, x.EndTimeStamp, 134165256277210658) AS EndTimeStamp
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SourceName,
            Active,
            LEAD(Active) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY TicksTimeStamp) NextActive,
            TicksTimeStamp AS StartTimeStamp,
            LEAD(TicksTimeStamp) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY TicksTimeStamp) EndTimeStamp
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Path = N'App1' and TicksTimeStamp >= 132165256277210658 and TicksTimeStamp < 134165256277210658
    ) x
    WHERE (x.Active = 1 and x.NextActive = 0) OR (x.Active = 1 and x.NextActive = null)
) y
GROUP BY y.SourceName
ORDER BY ProcessTimeStamp DESC, y.SourceName
```

The database structure is roughly as follows:

```
ID    Path    SourceName     TicksTimeStamp        Active
1     App1    Pipe1          132165256277210658     1
2     App1    Pipe1          132165256297210658     0
3     App1    Pipe1          132165956277210658     1
4     App2    Pipe2          132165956277210658     1
5     App2    Pipe2          132165956277210658     0
```

I use the ExecuteReader of C #. The same SQL statement runs on SQL Management for 4s, but the time returned by the ExecuteReader is 8-9s. Does the slow time have anything to do with this interface?

Comment: Add the existing indexes to your question.

Comment: For query performance questions, we need at a minimum: the tables *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really 'get' the entire query but I'm wondering about this part:

```
WHERE (x.Active = 1 and x.NextActive = 0) OR (x.Active = 1 and x.NextActive = null)
```

SQL doesn't really like OR's so why not convert this to

```
WHERE x.Active = 1 and ISNULL(x.NextActive, 0) = 0
```

This might cause a completely different query plan. (or not)

As CharlieFace mentioned, probably best to share the query plan so we might get an idea of what's going on.

PS: I'm also not sure what those 'ticksTimestamps' represent, but it looks like you're fetching a pretty wide range there, bigger volumes will also cause longer processing time. Even though you only return the top 10 it still has to go through the entire range to calculate those durations.

Comment: ticksTimestamps comes from the following way, representing a time.   ULONGLONG ullTimeStamp = 0; FILETIME ft;        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);  memcpy_s(&ullTimeStamp, sizeof(FILETIME ), &ft, sizeof(FILETIME ));

Comment: I tried your plan, which is 1s faster than my original one. I intend to find the following information in a 100 million level database: Find the top 10 sources whose active status changes from 1 to 0 or has been 1 for the longest time in a period of time. The timestamp is used to obtain the time difference.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Charlieface.  I think the index you want is as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Table1 (Path, TicksTimeStamp) INCLUDE (SourceName, Active);
```

You can add both indexes (with different names of course) and see which one the execution engine chooses.

Comment: I add index to the SQL volume of 5 million, but the query speed is almost the same as that without index.

Comment: If you post a query plan, we might able to offer a better suggestion.

Comment: I intend to find the following information in a 100 million level database:  Find the top 10 sources whose active status changes from 1 to 0 or has been 1 for the longest time in a period of time.

Comment: We cannot help without a query plan.  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest adding the following index which should help the inner query using `LEAD`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON Table1 (SourceName, TicksTimeStamp, Path) INCLUDE (Active);
```

The key point of the above index is that it should allow the lead values to be rapidly computed.  It also has an `INCLUDE` clause for `Active`, to cover the entire select.

Comment: I would have though putting `Path` at the beginning would make more sense